# Are the miners concerned with what the pool operators do with their hashpower?

Tags: mining-pools, governance, pool-operators

I've stumbled upon a few posts on the Bitcoin forum about miners claiming that they don't care what the pool operators do with their hashing power as long as they are paid, and some others that are more concerned than that. Is the bulk of the miners concerned with what the pool operators do with their hashpower?

Comment: It's safe to say that users of p2pool care, and users of Deepbit don't care, so you can get something by looking at the sizes of these two pools.

Comment: I don't think this question is a good fit ... the best possible answer here would only give the opinions of some of the miners, no good way to know how most miners or hashpower is represented.

Comment: @ripper234 If there is a consensus in the Bitcoin community about the issue, it can be given. If there is no consensus, that can also be stated as an answer to this question.

Comment: I'm confused: what could they do, other than mining? At worst they could use it to mine compatible currencies... is there anything else they could do?

Comment: @Lohoris: See http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/what-is-the-story-behind-the-attack-on-coiledcoin for an example. They can also create double-spending or DoS attacks on the Bitcoin network if they're large enough. Or include too many or too few transactions.

Comment: @Lohoris This would be a good topic for a separate question.